# Android : Disable 1.5 cupcake animation transitions

Tags: android, animation, screen, transition

Long story short, how can I disable the screen transitions between activities? We implemented our own tab handler if you will, and now it is doing a transition between tabs, which looks pretty tacky. Thanks!

Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION`

Comment: This constant is available only in 2.0 (API Level 5) and on.

Answer (score 2):

The Spare Parts app you find in the emulator, on self-built images and (i suppose) in the source tree let's you turn on/off those transitions(globally!). You may want to take a look at its source to get a clue how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be starting a whole new Activity for each tab. You should be embedding each Activity inside a android.app.ActivityGroup and use a android.app.LocalActivityManager.

Comment: Actually I do need each one to be it's own activity. I have to launch each 'tab' as an activity. Its a long story, but because of the way the camera displays (Landscape) we can't get tabs to rotate to look like portrait w/ the camera preview. If you do force it to rotate the camera preview rotates 90 degrees, and is off. Long story short, I think I can use  WindowManager.LayoutParams.