# Android, how to disable the 'wipe' effect when starting a new activity?

Tags: android

In my application, how do I disable the transition animation that shows the new activity layout enter from the right and the old one exit to left?

Versions 2.0 -> 2.2 if relevant.

Comment: might help you :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881195/android-disable-1-5-cupcake-animation-transitions

Comment: I saw that before posting. Not helpful at all unfortunately.

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CaseyB response is good we can set an animation

```
getWindow().setWindowAnimations(int);
```

but since Android SDK 2.0 you will use **overridePendingTransition()**, to change the transition animation, this is an example loading my App from the SplashScreen.

```
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.SplashScreen);

              new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                              Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,     AndroidNews.class);
                              SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                              SplashScreen.this.finish();

                              overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,
                                      R.anim.splashfadeout);
                      }
              }, 3000);
      }
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Add this flag to your intent: **android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION**.

Android docs states:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will prevent the system from applying an activity transition animation to go to the next activity state.

BTW: don't use it to set fire to an orphanage please :)

Answer (score 4):

You can tell the OS what kind of animation you want to use to bring your activity up, or none at all.  Just use:

[`getWindow().setWindowAnimations(int);`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/Window.html#setWindowAnimations(int))