# How to switch activity without animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-intent

How can I use properly the Intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` in AndroidManifest file? I supose my problem is trivial, but I can't find good example or solution to it.

```xml
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:name="android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION" />
    </intent-filter>
```

However no error is reported by compliator, but `data` isn't correct.
I just want to disable animation in case switching between activities. I can use `getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);` in onCreate or onResume rather but using flag is better way, isn't it?

I can use also in code:

```java
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), newactivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to use this flag in Android Manifest. To disable animation also in case returning from second activity to first.

Comment: I have found the sugestion to use theme - by defining enter, exit animations for activities or entire application. Can someone give me more informations about it?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You can create a style,

```
 <style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

and set it as theme for your activity in the manifest:

```
   <activity android:name=".ui.ArticlesActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
    </activity>
```

You can also define a style to specify custom entry and exit animations.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnterAnimation

Comment: Thanks, this works just great especially for transparent/dialog themed activities excluded from recents with a different task affinity. Without this the animation kept showing creating very odd results for a dialog being opened!

Comment: this no longer seems to work for Lollipop/Android 5.0?

Comment: I have Android 5 and it works for me. My app style looks like this: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>

Comment: Works perfectly in 6.0 also.  A great tip.  As I ask below, I wonder how to disable the animation which happens when ***first launching an app** ... is there a way ?!

Comment: will crash if you extend AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 220):

If your context is an activity you can call **overridePendingTransition**:

> Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or
>   finish to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

So, programmatically:

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), newactivity.class));
this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Comment: is it possible to do it via adb too?

Comment: @TalAngel the `overridePendingTransition` was added in API level 5. So no it does not work on "every" Android version but I guess you target a higher API level then 5.

Answer (score 58):

Try this code,

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), newactivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
```

Comment: This really helps when starting activity from service.

Comment: Tryed on Android 12: it works fine starting the NewActivity. If you call finish() in NewActivity, however, an animation will be present.

Answer (score 30):

You can also just do this in all the activities that you dont want to transition from:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

I like this approach because you do not have to mess with the style of your activity.

Comment: A great tip. I wonder how to disable the animation which happens when ***first launching an app** ... is there a way ?!

Comment: @Fattie Override the onStart() method of your launching activity and place the same code in that.

Answer (score 11):

The line in the theme style works fine, yet that replaces the animation with a white screen. Especially on a slower phone - it is really annoying.
So, if you want an instant transition - you could use this in the theme style:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a one-liner solution that works for as low as `minSdkVersion 14` which you should insert in you `res/styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

like so:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

After starting intent you can use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
```

If used, intent will work with no animations or transitions

Comment: overridePendingTransition seems like it won't do anything since there is no transition pending when the function is called. I added the flag for no animation to my code and it worked as expected (without needing the override).

Answer (score 5):

This is not an example use or an explanation of how to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION`, however it does answer how to disable the `Activity` switching animation, as asked in the question title:

[Android, how to disable the 'wipe' effect when starting a new activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187817/android-how-to-disable-the-wipe-effect-when-starting-a-new-activity)

Answer (score 2):

create your own style overriding android:Theme

```
<style name="noAnimationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then use it in manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/noAnimationStyle">
</activity>
```