# Android new Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view, android-imagebutton

In my Android application, all my views are like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcUdk.jpg (**reuploaded**)

I mean:

- I have a LinearLayout with a background red color for my App Title;
- **4 ImageButtons, when I click in each of them, I acess a specific view**;
- The content.

I'm debugging on my Samsung Galaxy S3. Everytime I click in a ImageButton (Menu1 - Menu4), the new Activity/View open, with a fadein effect (because my Galaxy S3, I guess) and It's working. But it's disturbing, the effect. I use some apps that I don't see the "fade in" effect every time I change the current view.

So: How can I start a new Intent without the "fadeIn" effect, because it's making a big history of views, everytime I click in one ImageButton, a new view open, with this boring effect.

I do the ImageButton actions like this:

```
Intent nextView = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(nextView);
```

The "FadeIn" is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcfgn6kqFUI (1min 1sec), for example.
Everytime I click the button my view open with this "effect".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Try executing this code **after** the startActivity():

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

EDIT:
Another way would be to set a specific style for your activity:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

Source: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation)

EDITEDIT:

You want to run only a single task of your activities. What you need to do is add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the activities that you want to be run only once inside your *AndroidManifest.xml* file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Menu1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    ... />
```

Comment: Hey, @user3249477, I think it's kinda working. The boring fadeIn effect is over. But is this a good way?

Comment: By the way, it's not "cleanning" the history.
I mean, if I'm on Menu1, then go Menu2, then go Menu1, then go Menu2, then go Menu1, then go Menu2 if I press "back button" (on my device), I go back to Menu1, then press again and Menu2. I wanted to: back to Menu1 and back again: exit application. Any idea?

Comment: And please don't combine multiple questions. If this one was answered select the correct answer and ask another one.