# Android transitionless Activity transition

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there anyway to make a Activity switch to another activity in a way that it isn't noticeable?

So in this case lets say Activity A and B are basically just empty white screens.  I want A to switch to B without the user being able to notice.  Is that possible?

Comment: Try custom transition animations, fade out A and fade in B might not be noticeable http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html
This also might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you want an specific Activity with no animations in or out of it just override `onPause` and `onResume` of that Activity like this:

```
@Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

or you can do this when starting an activity to remove the transition animation:

```
ActivityA.this.startActivity(intentToActivityB);
ActivityA.this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```