# How to design the footer as fixed in all activity in android

Tags: android, footer, android-tablayout

I am new for android,I have a footer tab-layout i want that tab layout to be present in all the activities it should be fixed, once going to the new activities or fragments it shouldn't be created again(shouldn't appear that it created then on reaching that activity or fragment). How should i achieve this? I surfed many related question but none matches my requirement. Kindly help me with this. [Sample image](http://toknow.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2015-01-091.png) . i want to achieve something like the sample image.

Comment: You can use only one activity, with two fragmetns, one for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having one activity and simply switching out fragments for the "content" area.

Otherwise you have to save the state of the footer and make it again in every activity. To have it *feel* seamless you can [remove the transition animation between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation).

Comment: how to remove the transition animation between activity?@dcow

Comment: @mohamedrefak edited answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation

Answer (score 0):

Make a footer layout file and then use `include` in all layout file you want to display that footer,

```
<include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

use `weightSum` to manage height of footer in all screen

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentTabHost.html). By default the tabs are shown above the screen, which is recommended by android. You can bring it down. [Here](https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost) and [here](https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/) are some examples.

You need to call the `setup()` method of the `FragmentTabHost` to initialise it. The content are is loaded as fragments. Use `newTabSpec()` method to add tabs to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple design one fragmenet and wherever you want you can put it in xml, the click events can be defined in that Fragment globally:) –