# Is it possible to start an activity via ADB without animation

Tags: android, android-activity, adb

I know it's possible to have **no animation** when starting an activity via code ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6972295/878126), for example), but is it possible to do so via adb too, even for activities that were supposed to have an animation ?

Also, is it possible to have no animation when going back from this opened activity?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the ADB Shell Activity Manager specification for  arguments here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#IntentSpec

we can see that there is a `-f` option for Intent flags.

Th Intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` has constant value: `65536`

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION

Putting that together you could write something like:

```
am start -a com.example.ACTION_NAME -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName -f 65536
```

Comment: I think it removes the animation of starting the activity. Is it possible to do it for closing it too? I use "input keyevent 4" (back button) to close the activity.

Comment: Not sure about removing the animation while closing an activity via adb.  Have you tried different closing strategies (back button, sending a finish Intent, etc)?  Perhaps instead of closing that activity you could simply send another intent to start your original activity?

Comment: Interesting idea. You mean I should use some flags for the intent of the activity I have now? Suppose I have ActivityA, and another app has ActivityB, I want to start AcrtivityB of the other app and then go back to ActivityA.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below command to start an activity via adb,

```
am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

Comment: I wrote : with no animation